# Can't replace accents on string (UTF8-Problem)

Tags: php, string

If I echo my string
    `<?php echo $string; ?>`
It returns
    `Vítor`

But I want to replace that 'í' with 'i' to make a clean username.
I've tried to use the following function

```
$unwanted_array = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                        'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                        'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                        'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                        'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );` 
$novouser_uu = strtr($novouser_u, $unwanted_array);
```

But it returns
    `v�tor`
If I use utf8_encode it returns `vãtor` and utf8_decode returns `v?tor`

Replacing with iconv just removes the character or leaves a question mark '?'

There is no html on this page's code because it being accessed via AJAX, but in the page where it comes from I have the header charset set to UTF-8.
Also, in the config.php file, I have
     `mysqli_set_charset($ligacao, "utf8");`

**EDIT:**

I had `$novouser_u = strtolower($novouser);` before doing the replacement, and after removing `strtolower` the issues was solved.

Comment: I think the `strtr` is not a multibyte safe function. I would look at using `iconv`.

Comment: @user3783243 iconv returned me a question mark `v?tor`

Comment: Actually what you have works for me https://3v4l.org/8ZSOe. What system are you running? You are sure you have `Vítor` prior to this function call?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, I do, when I echo the string it returns Vítor, but after any replacement it gives the invalid character or question marks. Running Wampserver 3.1.4, PHP 7.2.10

Comment: @user3783243 found the issue... I had `$novouser_u =strtolower($novouser)` before and after removing it, the replacement was done properly, sorry for this mistake and thank you for your time!

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the bytecodes for the thing you want to replace.

```
<?php
$unwanted_array = array(
    "\xc3\xad" => "i",
    "\xc5\xa0" => "S",
);
$novouser_u = "Vítor";
$novouser_uu = strtr($novouser_u, $unwanted_array);
echo "$novouser_uu\n";

$novouser_u = "Šup";
$novouser_uu = strtr($novouser_u, $unwanted_array);
echo "$novouser_uu\n";
```

Comment: How using `"\xc3\xad"` is better than `"í"`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an actual [transliterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) instead:

```
$in = <<<'_E_'
'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );
_E_;

$tl = Transliterator::create('Latin-ASCII;');
echo $tl->transliterate($in);
```

Output:

```
'S'=>'S', 's'=>'s', 'Z'=>'Z', 'z'=>'z', 'A'=>'A', 'A'=>'A', 'A'=>'A', 'A'=>'A', 'A'=>'A', 'A'=>'A', 'AE'=>'A', 'C'=>'C', 'E'=>'E', 'E'=>'E',
'E'=>'E', 'E'=>'E', 'I'=>'I', 'I'=>'I', 'I'=>'I', 'I'=>'I', 'N'=>'N', 'O'=>'O', 'O'=>'O', 'O'=>'O', 'O'=>'O', 'O'=>'O', 'O'=>'O', 'U'=>'U',
'U'=>'U', 'U'=>'U', 'U'=>'U', 'Y'=>'Y', 'TH'=>'B', 'ss'=>'Ss', 'a'=>'a', 'a'=>'a', 'a'=>'a', 'a'=>'a', 'a'=>'a', 'a'=>'a', 'ae'=>'a', 'c'=>'c',
'e'=>'e', 'e'=>'e', 'e'=>'e', 'e'=>'e', 'i'=>'i', 'i'=>'i', 'i'=>'i', 'i'=>'i', 'd'=>'o', 'n'=>'n', 'o'=>'o', 'o'=>'o', 'o'=>'o', 'o'=>'o',
'o'=>'o', 'o'=>'o', 'u'=>'u', 'u'=>'u', 'u'=>'u', 'y'=>'y', 'th'=>'b', 'y'=>'y' );
```

The full documentation on transliteration rules can be found on [icu-project.org](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general).